# How to count the current sound loop in play(0, 30)

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I'm playing a sound file (mp3) and looping it 30 times.

```
soundChannel = soundLoop.play(0, 30);
```

I would like to display the current loop as a number in a textField. Have tried using an eventListener to determine when each loop restarts, but I think that Event.SOUND_COMPLETE dispatches when the sound is loaded and not for each repeated play.

I'd be grateful for some guidance in this area. Thanks.

**Edit with working code**
Thanks to @Barış

```
    var lastPosition:Number;
    var loops:int=1;
    var timerLoops:Timer = new Timer(1000);
    timerLoops.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, startTimerLoops);

    function startTimerLoops():void
    {
        timerLoops.start();

        if(lastPosition > soundChannel.position)
            loops++;
            lastPosition = soundChannel.position;
            trace("Playing " + loops + " of 30" + "-" + lastPosition);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`soundChannel.position` is the time in milliseconds from the beginning of the sound. It is reset to 0 after the sound loops. You can track that to figure out if the sound looped.

Something like the following in your update/enterframe can work :

```
private function update():void
{
   if(lastPosition > soundChannel.position)
      loops++;
   lastPosition = soundChannel.position;
}
```

Comment: Would that require some sort of listener, to pick up each "reset to 0"?

Comment: Yeah this function is supposed to be a listener. It could be a timer event or an enter frame event. It has to be called regularly so that you can detect quickly when a loop happens.

Comment: Thanks @Barış I combined your function with a timer event and listener and it works perfectly. I've added the final code in my question above. Cheers!